# Are locally-stored Filemaker Go databases included in an iPad backup?

Tags: icloud, backup, ipados, filemaker

There are two options for backing up an iPad:

> - icloud
>
>   - Backup the most important data on your iPad to iCloud
> - This Computer
>
>   - A full backup of your iPad will be stored on this computer

Does either of these options backup a locally-stored database within Filemaker Go?

Answer (score 0):

Locally stored data such as that are backed up by both methods of backup.